# Converting NSArray to NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray, nsarray

As above. Would be helpful to know. Thanks!

Comment: adding "need this urgently" is likely to have the opposite effect...

Comment: This is like the third exact question on NSArray and NSMutableArray's today.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Here are two options:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)createMutableArray1:(NSArray *)array
{
    return [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:array];
}

- (NSMutableArray *)createMutableArray2:(NSArray *)array
{
    return [[array mutableCopy] autorelease];
}
```

Comment: Here's a conversion back to an NSArray: NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithArray:mutableArray];

Answer (score 18):

Use `-mutableCopy` and make sure to balance the retain count.

```
NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [[immutableArray mutableCopy] autorelease];
```

Comment: It's now: NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [immutableArray mutableCopy];

Comment: @MarcelMarino That's correct!

Answer (score 11):

Try this one

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:your_array_name];
```