# How to convert NSArray to NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);  
CFIndex nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook);

NSMutableArray *tempPeoples=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for(int i=0;i<nPeople;i++){

    ABRecordRef i1=CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allPeople, i);
    [tempPeoples addObject:i1];

//  [peoples addObject:i1];

}// end of the for loop
peoples=[tempPeoples copy];
```

This code gives exception b/c I want to convert NSMutableArray to NSArray
Please Help

Comment: Answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222122/converting-nsarray-to-nsmutablearray

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The subject reads, "How to convert `NSArray` to `NSMutableArray`". To get an `NSMutableArray` from an `NSArray`, use the class method on `NSMutableArray` +`arrayWithArray`:.

Your code does not show the declaration for peoples. Assuming it's declared as an `NSMutableArray`, you can run into problems if you try to treat it as such. When you send the copy message to an `NSMutableArray`, you get an immutable object, `NSArray`, so if you try to add an object to a copied `NSMutableArray`, you will get an error.

`CFArrayRef` is toll free bridged to `NSArray`, so you could simplify your code this way:

```
CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
//NSMutableArray *tempPeoples = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:(NSArray*)allPeople];
// even better use the NSMutableCopying protocol on NSArray
NSMutableArray *tempPeoples = [(NSArray*)allPeople mutableCopy];
CFRelease(allPeople);
return tempPeoples; // or whatever is appropriate to your code
```

In the above code tempPeoples is an autoreleased `NSMutableArray` ready for you to add or remove objects as needed.

Answer (score 4):

> This code gives exception b/c I want to convert NSMutableArray to NSArray

This is *very* unlikely. NSMutableArray is a derived class of NSArray, so copying in that direction isn't an issue.

Maybe you've got an error because you don't retain the array. `arrayWithArray` returns an `autorelease` object. Either use `[tempPeoples copy]` or `[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray: tempPeoples];`

Comment: I did ,but it is again giving following exception:2010-12-31 15:30:24.889 Appointment[2708:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSCFType isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x420f900'
2010-12-31 15:30:24.890 Appointment[2708:207] Stack: (
    30393435,
    2510714121,
    30775355,
    30344822,
    30197442,
    4347985,
    9508,
    3018252,

Comment: Well, I don't see the line causing the exception in the code you've shown, I can't help you there. Where do you call 'isEqualToString'?

Answer (score 4):

Simply you can do that

```
NSArray *yourArray ; // Static Array
NSMutableArray* subArrayData = [yourArray mutableCopy];
```