# Error occurs when I convert NSMutableArray to NSArray

Tags: nsmutablearray

I want to convert NSMutableArray to NSArray to it gives error following is code

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);  
CFIndex nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook);

tempPeoples=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for(int i=0;i<nPeople;i++){

    ABRecordRef i1=CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allPeople, i);
    [tempPeoples addObject:i1];

//[peoples addObject:i1];

}// end of the for loop

// Peoples is NSArray
// peoples=[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray: tempPeoples];

peoples=[NSArray arrayWithArray:tempPeoples];
```

Please help

Comment: Same code, same problem but even less description than your earlier question: [How to convert NSArray to NSMutableArray](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4569478/how-to-convert-nsarray-to-nsmutablearray)

Comment: Please explain on which line do you get the error, and what exactly is the error. Also @Abizem is correct - you've already posted a similar question, and the answers on that question are correct.

Comment: Ali. Not getting a solution is no reason to post the same question again. You were asked for further code/information in your original question; you should have answered those requests.

Comment: ok,sorry ,I found the solution thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution using following code

```
 ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();

NSArray *allPeople = (NSArray*)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);  
CFIndex nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook);

tempPeoples= [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];

for(int i=0;i<nPeople;i++){

    ABRecordRef i1=CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allPeople, i);

    NSString* name = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(i1,kABPersonFirstNameProperty);

    [tempPeoples addObject:name];

//  [peoples addObject:i1];

}// end of the for loop

peoples=[NSArray arrayWithArray:tempPeoples];
```